# MySQL, how do I hash a column from on table and move it to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, hashbytes

I have a table with a list of credit card numbers and I would like to hash those numbers and add them to another column in the same table.

I am able to Hash the card numbers:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', PlainText)  
FROM CreditCard
```

and I get a good list of hashed numbers but I can't seem to get those hashed numbers into another column. I tried to update the column with the hashed data using:

```
insert into Hash_TEMP(Hashcc)
  SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', PlainText) 
  from CreditCard
```

but the data doesn't look like hash numbers

What it looks like :

```
!¹^«±O&†Âûlà´Mq
```

what is should look like:

```
0x07CB9B44650188F693432A82687F5132681AF0F6
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: is this working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of 'Hashcc' in Hash_temp table to binary and try your code.

Comment: used this or was anyother issue?